# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/RemovalListener

Tags: java, api, telegram-bot

I want to work telegram API, I create Bot in telegram and set username and get a token but I can not  connect with my java code please help me
I use this code

```
ApiContextInitializer.init();
TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
try {
    telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TradeBot());
} catch (TelegramApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and my proxy is set and test connection is right

```
public class TradeBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "xxx";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "xxx";

    }
}
```

and after run code give this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/RemovalListener
    at com.google.inject.internal.InheritingState.<init>(InheritingState.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.getState(InjectorShell.java:208)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.lock(InjectorShell.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext.getInjector(ApiContext.java:48)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.ApiContext.getInstance(ApiContext.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:16)
    at TradeBot.<init>(TradeBot.java:6)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Was answered here:

[Google Guice can't find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091053/google-guice-cant-find-class)

You need the correct version of the `com.google.guava/guava` dependency related to the `com.google.inject/guice` library that you are already using.